# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when opening XAML

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# WPF project I can open just fine in VS 2010 Ultimate or 2013 Ultimate.

I can edit it and run it from either.

When I double click the window.xaml, it crashes 2013.

I disabled then uninstalled my extensions. Still crashes.

I spent more than half the day uninstalling [(uninstall is broken, btw)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2014/01/21/uninstalling-visual-studio-2013-with-vsupdate-error-element-not-found.aspx) and re-installing VS 2013 Ultimate. Still crashes.

Per comment, here's a screenshot of the error:
[image: error message]

Actually just tried to create a clean WPF project and it crashes the same way while attempting to create a new WPF project.

Comment: Do you use custom Tools as Devexpress, Syncfusion or others?

Comment: @verdesrobert I uninstalled all tools and extensions.

Comment: Did you reinstall Visual Studio after removing all the Tools?

Comment: @verdesrobert Good question, I really don't remember the order. I'd rather not go another 5 hours trying the whole process again unless you have good reason to believe doing it in a different order will work.

Comment: Could you post the content of  %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\PUTYOURVSVERSIONHERE\ActivityLog.xml

Comment: If there's no folder for your version or it is empty, run `devenv.exe /log`

Comment: @verdesrobert Excellent thinking! I looked and it still had a reference to Python Tools which I now remember hung during uninstall. I re-installed that and uninstalled and it works now. Want to post something about looking in ActivityLog.xml for anything out of place and I'll accept it as the answer?

Comment: It was between my suspects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always check this folder for any VS errors

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\PUTYOURVSVERSIONHERE\ActivityLog.xml
```

If the folder doesn't exist or is empty, run Visual Studio with this command:

```
devenv.exe /log
```

Comment: I looked and there was still a reference to Python Tools which I now remember hung during uninstall. I re / un installed Python Tools and xaml files open now.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons. [This one](http://i4.connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797072/designer-crashes-in-visual-studio-2013-with-system-runtime-remoting-remotingexception) for example was because of an outdated driver. There may be workarounds, however which one to use will depend on the error you see. Can you update your question with the error message?

Comment: This was the cause of my issue, I tracked it down by looking in the Event Viewer. The designer actually crashes